# need google.maps.Geocoder() equivalent in bing maps

Tags: google-maps, extjs, bing, bing-maps

need `google.maps.Geocoder()` equivalent in bing maps

I'm writing a wrapper for bing in extjs. I have done this using gmappanel and i am converting that step by step. I need the equivalent function of `google.maps.Geocoder()` in bing or can u provide some pointers on bing geocoder?

Answer (score 1):

You have two different way to do what you want.

First you can use the Bing Maps REST API that contain a method for what you want to do.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx) is a link that explains how to use this API to geocode query.

The second way to do that is to use the SearchManager and his geocode or search method.

See the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868062.aspx) to see how it work.

Hope it can help you.